# jQuery: how to update value in place?

Tags: jquery

I want to edit data in a table using jQuery. 
The HTML markup is:

```
<tr id="unique_rid1">
    <td>15/01/2012</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="edit_work_done" id="unique_rid1">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

When user clicks on "Edit", this link becomes "Update" and the table cell contaning the number 4 turns into a text field.
Here is the jQuery code for that:

```
//change the work done to be a form when "edit" is clicked
var toUpdate;
$(".edit_work_done").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('edit_work_done').addClass('update_work_done').html("Update!");
    toUpdate = $(this).parent().parent().children('td').eq(1);
    var Hours = toUpdate.html();
    toUpdate.html('<input type="number" value="'+ Hours +'" class="new_hour span1"/>');
});
//change the work done to be static value when "Update!" is clicked
$(".update_work_done").live("click", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('update_work_done').addClass('edit_work_done').html("Edit");
    var newHours = $(this).parent().parent().find("input.new_hour").val();
    toUpdate = $(this).parent().parent().children('td').eq(1);
    toUpdate.html(newHours);
});
```

However, "live" catches the class change immediately and does not allow the `<input>` tag to come up or the link to change to Update!

Question: How should I bind this event? (as a simple "click" event does not capture the dynamically updated class change)

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated. Use `on()` or `delegate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give live to both

```
var toUpdate;
$(".edit_work_done").live("click", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('edit_work_done').addClass('update_work_done').html("Update!");
    toUpdate = $(this).parent().parent().children('td').eq(1);
    var Hours = toUpdate.html();
    toUpdate.html('<input type="number" value="'+ Hours +'" class="new_hour span1"/>');
});
```